# C# store DateTime to Timestamp column in MYSQL

Tags: c#, datetime

How to convert C# `Datetime.Today`, into `Timestamp` format 10/20/2011 12:00:00 in mysql?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in C# or how to do this in Mysql?

Comment: Have you considered using parameterized queries instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to get the date time as a string in that format then you can do...

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

See [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) for extra formatting options for the DateTime ToString method

Though from my understanding of MySQL it will accept a timestamp in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. I would recommend doing this as it will ensure dates like 05/08/2011 are parsed correctly for the right month and day...

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Correct format string to `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` (according to OP question) and you get +1 from me :)

Comment: it suppose to be pm but store in mysql it is am

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

and if you want more/other time formats, check [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like following and use return value as timestamp for Sql.

```
public static string GiveMeTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
 return value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:ffff");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the overloaded [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method which takes a string argument for the format.

Answer (score 0):

This Possibly may assist someone with the same approach and thought that I had:

To test directly in MYSQL Workbench:

```
INSERT into tblDemo VALUES (898,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());

create table tblDemo (ScenarioID INT(10),
          ProcessTime  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NOT NUll);
```

Now compile the string in your C# Code like so:

```
    string query = "INSERT into tblDemo " + 
                    "VALUES (" +  ScenarioID + "," +  " CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
```

Note the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() in quotes in the above query

Output:
'2021-03-04 17:52:30'